# Ruby on Rails is mongodb - mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-6

I am not able to install the 'mongoid' gem in my project. I'm using rails 6.0.0 and it's always giving me this error

Installing mongo 2.14.0 (was 2.14.0.rc1)
Errno :: EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink -
(spec / support /../../. mod / drivers-evergreen-tools / .evergreen / ocsp,
C: /Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/spec/support/ocsp)
An error occurred while installing mongo (2.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mongo -v '2.14.0' --source 'https: // rubygems.org /' '
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
mongoid was resolved to 7.0.11, which depends on
Mongo

I have already changed versions of the mongoid gem but there is always a need

Comment: I assume that error is caused when you run that command `gem install mongo -v '2.14.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' `, right?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
 gem install mongo -v '2.14.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

with ADMIN permissions